# two different gnome-software stores - same os Xubuntu 20.04lts - starting snap-store starts gnome-software?

Tags: snap, flatpak, gnome-software

I recently fresh reinstalled Xubuntu 20.04lts on two of my pcs.
Suddenly after a few weeks, i discovered a couple of differences between these pcs, were i did not alter anything.
It seems that the Software store (gnome-software) looks like being different versions compared between both systems.
one has a Source tab on the top right next to minimize, the other lacks that and has a gear for options there. (containing nothing special only software and updates, and two options for updating software) This source tab gives access to flatpak software, and a little extra sources. Also i cannot find this tab anywhere on the other pc in the gnome-software application.
The other point is, that on this pc, which has extra sources for software like flatpak, the snap-store seems to be replaced for gnome-software. What means, that when i click the snap-store icon, it starts gnome-software. also i tried running it by terminal with snap-store, but the same result. i dont know what happened here.
first of all, how can i get these flatpak resources also, with that source tab on the other pc (in gnome-software), and how do i ¨restore¨ the snap-store to working state. the other pc by the way does have a working snap-store. i have compared the ppas of both, and there are no differences, and nothing has been added.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I [have read before](https://jatan.blog/2020/05/02/ubuntu-snap-obsession-has-snapped-me-off-of-it/) - the Ubuntu Software is a snap application, it does not have integration with FlatPak.

So you may to decide removing it:

```
snap remove snap-store
```

and install deb-packaged GNOME Software with FlatPak and Snap plugins instead:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-software gnome-software-plugin-flatpak gnome-software-plugin-snap
```